# What is the maximum frequency of an AC current?

Tags: stepper-motor, ac, frequency-response

I saw that the rpm of a synchronous motor is proportional to the frequency of current alteration and I was wondering if there is a theoretical maximum frequency (regardless of magnet strength)? Also could changing the frequency be used to control the speed of a synchronous motor?

Comment: AC currents can reach the GHz range and higher. So don't look for a "theoretical maximum frequency" in motor applications - look for mechanical properties of materials that limit the frequency your motor can exploit -material strength, bearing lubrication, etc.

Comment: @BrianDrummond in a practical sense, you will also find that the inductance in a motor's windings will kill off high (enough) AC frequencies.  I'll bet that happens well past the speed at which the motor flies apart!

Comment: Theoretically, there is no limit except Plank frequency (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Derived_units) when photon becomes a blackhole).

Practically, more than several Ghz it is difficult or very inefficient, because of different reasons like resistance, radiation, etc. Maybe this is one of the reasons, why they cannot make computer CPU with a frequency higher than 4GHz. But about motors previous comments are correct.